# Как написать код без условного оператора?

Tags: c++, условия

Как написать данную программу без условных операторов (без if)?

Вот условие программы:

> На вход программе подаются два целых числа n, m.где 0 < n<=12.
>   0<=m<60, указывающие момент времени "n часов m минут". Определите
>   наименьшее число полных минут, через которое часовая и минутная
>   стрелки расположатся на циферблате перпендикулярно друг другу.
>   Вещественную арифметику не использовать.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
    long long m, n;
    std::cin >> m >> n;
    m %= 12;
    long long x = n * 6 - m * 30 - n * 0.5;
    if ((x == 90) || (x == -90) || (x == 270) || (x == -270)) {
        std::cout << 0 << '\n';
    } else {
        long long next = (long long) ((2 * (270 * (x > 90) + 90 * (x <= 90) - x)) / 11);
        std::cout << next << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну вместо if можно сделать табличку для диспечеризации.

Comment: `((x == 90) || (x == -90) || (x == 270) || (x == -270)) && std::cout << 0 << '\n'`